# how to plot sequence of partial sums in Maple

Tags: sequences-and-series, maple

I've seen other questions and tried to use internet and the built-in help but I'm still at a loss.

Given the sequence seq((n,1/2^n),n..20)), I want to plot the corresponding sequence of partial sums, but I can't figure out how.

I have:

```
with(plots):
PartialSums([seq(1/2^n, n = 1 .. 20)])
```

And that gives me the sequence, but how do I plot it with respect to n?

Comment: Does this help? http://web.clark.edu/jmitchell/maple/Sequences%20in%20MAPLE/Sequences%20and%20Series%20in%20MAPLE.html

Comment: I saw that one but it mostly just confused me. This is making me feel really dumb.

Comment: That page also does series as just a solution, not a plot of the sequence of partial sums. It plots a sequence, but that returns different values than PartialSums (the function I tried, which returns a list containing the partial sum for each n in the range)

Comment: incidentally, googling "maple "partialsums" plot" brings up this page as the first hit XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
L := ListTools:-PartialSums([seq(1/2^n, n = 1 .. 20)]):

plots:-listplot(L);
```

Comment: That is very close to what I need, but I need discrete points ...

Comment: You can add any usual plot option into the mix. For example, 'style=point' can be put into that call to 'listplot', and so on. Issue the command ?plot,options will show a help page.

Comment: You are my new best friend :)